# XGBoost DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

**Context**: Trying to fit my XGBoost model but getting a ValueError Msg. I've looked at similar posts but the difference is that ALL my columns are either Int or Float. I have no object, categorical columns.

X_train.info() yields:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the capitalization! The type of your integer columns is probably [`pandas.Int64Dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html) (nullable, object-like), not a plain `builtins.int` or `numpy.int64` (not nullable, numeric).

Can you cast your presumed integer columns to `numpy.int64`? Does the training succeed then?

If your integer columns contain missing values, then you probably need to convert them to `numpy.float32` instead.

Comment: worked like a charm when converting to numpy.int64. I had no nnulls btw