# XGBoost's requires int or float when I actually have int and float

Tags: python, databricks, xgboost

I have the following data:

x_train is `np.ndarray`, y_train is `np.ndarray` and model is `xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier`. The types are:

```
print(type(x_train))
print(x_train.dtype)

>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>> float64

print(type(y_train))
print(y_train.dtype)

>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>> float64

print(type(model))

>> xgboost.sklearn.XGBClassifier
```

I am using Databricks Runtime 12.2 LTS ML which corresponds to `xgboost==1.7.2`.

Getting the following error:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

>> XGBoostError: [09:28:22] ../src/data/data.cc:254: All feature_types must be one of {int, float, i, q, c}.
```

y_train is actually a vector or 1s and 0s, I have also tried with casting it to `np.int32` or `np.int64`. Then, I tried casting it to `builtins.int` and `builtins.float`, as such:

```
x_train = np.array(x_train, dtype=float)
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype=int)
print(x_train.dtype)
print(y_train.dtype)

>>float64
>>int64
```

Same error as before.

I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76160048/xgboost-dataframe-dtypes-for-data-must-be-int-float-or-bool) but this does not help me as my types are different. I would prefer not to have to convert from numpy dtypes since these have worked in the past and my config files are set in such as way ..

Other relevant packages: sklearn==0.0.post7 and scikit-learn==1.0.2. You can reproduce the error as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb

params = {'base_score': 0.5,
 'booster': 'gbtree',
 'callbacks': 'null',
 'colsample_bylevel': 1,
 'colsample_bynode': 1,
 'colsample_bytree': 1,
 'early_stopping_rounds': 'null',
 'enable_categorical': False,
 'eval_metric': 'aucpr',
 'feature_types': 'null',
 'gamma': 7,
 'gpu_id': -1,
 'grow_policy': 'lossguide',
 'importance_type': 'null',
 'interaction_constraints': '',
 'learning_rate': 0.05610004032698376,
 'max_bin': 256,
 'max_cat_threshold': 64,
 'max_cat_to_onehot': 4,
 'max_delta_step': 0,
 'max_depth': 2,
 'max_leaves': 0,
 'min_child_weight': 1,
 'monotone_constraints': (),
 'n_estimators': 1275,
 'n_jobs': 4,
 'num_parallel_tree': 1,
 'objective': 'binary:logistic',
 'predictor': 'auto',
 'random_state': 0,
 'reg_alpha': 0,
 'reg_lambda': 60,
 'sampling_method': 'uniform',
 'scale_pos_weight': 11.507905606798213,
 'subsample': 1,
 'tree_method': 'hist',
 'use_label_encoder': False,
 'validate_parameters': 1,
 'verbosity': 0}

model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)
x = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,10)).astype(np.float64)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1,100).astype(np.int64)
model.fit(x,y)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this under `xgboost==1.7.2` with empty numpy arrays of type float64 and int64, or arrays of type float64 and float64.

Comment: If you use np.empty(100).astype(np.int64) for y, you will not get this error since it will not be a classification problem to begin with. You need to use np.random.uniform(0,1,100).astype(np.int64). More specifically: x = np.empty([100,10]).astype(np.float64)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1,100).astype(np.int64)

Comment: I tried `y_train = np.random.uniform(0,2,100).astype(np.int64)` and still get no error. Can you add more information about how to set up the arrays to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have only now noticed that I am forcing the `feature_types` to be `'null'` in the params dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with **float32** instead of **float64** or **int32** instead of **int64**?

that works for me